# The signature of Resolver.url in Sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

When I am using sbt-io. I have a question for different resolver style configuration for sbt.

1. resolvers ++= Seq( ....
2. resolvers += Resolver.url()...

In the 2nd way. The signature of it defined like this:

```
def apply(name: String, baseURL: URL)(implicit basePatterns: Patterns): URLRepository =
            baseRepository(baseURL.toURI.normalize.toString)(URLRepository(name, _))
```

It looks like that the second way needs a Pattern and used in (URLRepository(name, _)), so for the consistent code style, my question is if I want to put it into 1st way resolvers ++= Seq(...), how can I do it ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

SBT lets you define a list of resolvers for your projects.

You can write something like this (in `build.sbt`):

```
resolvers ++= Seq("snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots",
                  "releases"  at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases")
```

and later add more resolvers using whatever syntax suits you:

```
resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver

resolvers += Resolver.url("my-test-repo", url)(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

resolvers += Resolver.url("my-test-repo", url)( Patterns("[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]"))

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")  // Or "snapshots"

resolvers += "oracle driver repo" at "http://dist.codehaus.org/mule/dependencies/maven2"
```

`+=` operator adds a single resolver to the list of resolvers defined so far, and `++=` adds all elements of a sequence. Notice that the `basePatterns` parameter is implicit, thus if you don't have to change the format a default pattern will be provided for you implicitly.

For more information see the official docs: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html.